# gnu Prolog powerset modification

Tags: list, prolog, set, substring, dcg

So i got this for powerset:

```
powerset([], []).
powerset([H|T], P) :- powerset(T,P).
powerset([H|T], [H|P]) :- powerset(T,P).
```

This generates all sets of a list. Is it possible to generate all sets in list order.

Example:

```
List = [a,b,c]
```

I want to get

```
[a],[a,b],[a,b,c],[b],[b,c],[c]
```

Note there is no `[a,c]` in this list of subsets since these are subsets starting from the left and going to the right.

I've tried using a combination of append and recursion, but that didn't work out as i wanted it to. Little stumped at this point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
powerset(L, [H|T]):-
  append([H|T], _, L).
powerset([_|L], P):-
  powerset(L, P).
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I was close. Seems to always be the case.

Comment: This does **not** produce the full powerset. For instance, it fails to produce [a, c] when asked what the powerset of [a, b, c] is.

Comment: @RasmusJ: Have you seen the question ? It clearly states that [a,c] should not be an answer for input [a,b,c]. OP wants "sets in list order" (check OP sample input/output for clarification)

Answer (score 3):

You want all <s>subsequences</s> substrings ([definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring#Substring)).  Grammars (DCGs) are best for this:

```
seq([]) -->
   [].
seq([E|Es]) -->
   [E],
   seq(Es).

... --> [] | [_], ... .

?- Es = [_|_], phrase((..., seq(Es), ...), [A,B,C]).
   Es = [A]
;  Es = [A, B]
;  Es = [A, B, C]
;  Es = [B]
;  Es = [B, C]
;  Es = [C]
;  false.
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this an old post, but I'm not gonna update it for no reasons.
the answer which is accepted with all the respect, generates all subsets separably, and does not generate a powerset.

a few days ago I was trying to implement a `powerSet/2` predicate, without use of built-in predicate `bagof/2`. but even with `bagof/2` and `setof/2` it's not very easy problem for beginners (generating all subset separably is another problem and much easier). so after implementing the solution I thought it's better to put it here in order to prevent people who are searching for this topic from mistakes.

#### My solution (without `bagof/2`)

```
generate(X, [Y], [[X| Y]]).

generate(X, S, P) :-
        S = [H| T],
        append([X], H, Temp),
        generate(X, T, Rest),
        append([Temp], Rest, P), !.

powerSet([], [[]]).

powerSet(Set, P) :-
        Set = [H| T],
        powerSet(T, PsT),
        generate(H, PsT, Ps),
%       write('trying to push '), print(H), write(' to '),
%       write('all elements of powerset of '), print(T), write(' which is '),
%       print(PsT), nl,
%       write('and the result is '), print(Ps), nl, nl,
        append(Ps, PsT, P), !.
```

code will be understood if consulted with the commented lines.

another solution is available [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Prolog) which uses built-in predicate `bagof/3`.

probably it would be more helpful now.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
powerset(A,B):-
    append(A,_,B);
    append(_,A,B).

test():-
    setof(X,powerset(X,[1,2,3]),L),
    writeln(L).
```