# Prolog powerset predicate

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog, powerset

I wish to define a predicate powerset(X, P) which is true when P is the powerset of X. Should work whether or not P is ground.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Which prolog are you working on? Is this homework?

Comment: STICStus. This is a practice question I cannot work out a solution to.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @gusbro: No, it's the difference between subsequence and substring.

Comment: @false: you are right. comment deleted (will delete this in a while)

Comment: @gusbro: Just noted this, because someone wants to close this question...

Answer (score 6):

Since you use SICStus Prolog you can use the subseq0(+Sequence, ?SubSequence) from library(lists), which "is true when SubSequence is a subsequence of Sequence, but may be Sequence itself" (Quoting from the manual http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.0.2/html/sicstus/lib_002dlists.html).

```
      ?- setof(X, subseq0([a,b,c],X), Xs).
      Xs = [[],[a],[a,b],[a,b,c],[a,c],[b],[b,c],[c]]
```

If you are not allowed to use library predicates you can implement the subseteq0 as explained in [gnu Prolog powerset modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146117/gnu-prolog-powerset-modification), which I quote here for the sake of completeness (with thanks to *gusbro*)

```
powerset([], []).
powerset([H|T], P) :- powerset(T,P).
powerset([H|T], [H|P]) :- powerset(T,P).
```

Comment: I just noted [this odd terminological problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence#Substring_vs._subsequence): A sequence and a string are often used synonymously, but a subsequence and a substring are not identical...

Comment: Somehow I'm used to this naming convention but indeed it is not very consistent.