# Prolog compute the permutation

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a permutation function [a,b]-->[[[a], [b]], [[a, b]]

I have this so far, but it doesn't work.

```
perm([],[]).
perm(L,[H|T]) :- append(V,[H|U],L), append(V,U,W), perm(W,T).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your example, it looks like you might actually be wanting the [*powerset*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), not the *permutation*, of the given list.

For instance, the powerset of `[a,b]` is the set {`[a,b]`, `[a]`, `[b]`, `[]`}.

To compute the powerset of a list of items in Prolog, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146427/206428) by @gusbro. If this helps you, also please upvote that answer.

If you want all solutions of the powerset of a list `L` at once, you can wrap the call to `powerset/2` in a `findall/3` call like this:

```
?- findall(S, powerset(L, S), Ss).
```

If, on the other hand, you're after the *partitions* (as you've mentioned in one of your earlier edits), consider the following:

```
partition(L, PL) :-
    partition(L, [], PL).

partition([], [], []).
partition([X|Xs], As, R) :-
    % add X into the new partition... 
    append(As, [X], NewAs),  
    partition(Xs, NewAs, R).
partition(L, [A|As], [[A|As]|R]) :-
    % ...or, collect the current non-empty partition
    partition(L, [], R).
```

The predicate `partition/2` takes a list and returns all partitions, as you've described. For example:

```
?- partition([a,b,c],L).
L = [[a, b, c]] ;
L = [[a, b], [c]] ;
L = [[a], [b, c]] ;
L = [[a], [b], [c]] ;
false.
```

Comment: `bagof/3` appears preferable to also treat variables nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Really? It seems to work in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- [user].
|: perm([],[]).
|: perm(L,[H|T]) :- append(V,[H|U],L), append(V,U,W), perm(W,T).
|: % user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 3 clauses
true.

?- perm([a,b,c], X).
X = [a, b, c] ;
X = [a, c, b] ;
X = [b, a, c] ;
X = [b, c, a] ;
X = [c, a, b] ;
X = [c, b, a] ;
false.

?- perm([a,b,c,d], X).
X = [a, b, c, d] ;
/* trimming 22 solutions */
X = [d, c, b, a] ;
false.
```

This also yields the number of answers you'd expect: 3! = 6, 4! = 24. What's not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Quick note: Prolog doesn't offer *functions*, but *relations*.

In this case, perm/2 will hold true when the arguments are one the permutation of the other.

I find this definition more readable than your.

```
perm([], []).
perm([E|Es], P) :-
    perm(Es, Q),
    select(E, P, Q).
```

It's almost the same as that of [permutation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=permutation/2)/2 SWI-Prolog, but hides a bug...