# Understanding the append syntax

Tags: prolog, append

I am having some trouble understanding this piece of code.

```
powerset(L, [H|T]):-
  append([H|T], _, L).
```

It originates from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146117/gnu-prolog-powerset-modification) and does exactly what I want; however, I would also like to understand the code that I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first consider the clause's single goal in isolation:

```
?- append([H|T], _, L).
```

What does this mean? With pure Prolog code, there is a good and convenient way to learn more about relations: Simply **post a query** on the toplevel and see what solutions look like.

Try it out! For example:

```
?- append([H|T], _, L).
L = [H|_1282],
T = [] ;
L = [H, _1078|_1096],
T = [_1078] ;
L = [H, _1078, _1084|_1108],
T = [_1078, _1084] ;
L = [H, _1078, _1084, _1090|_1120],
T = [_1078, _1084, _1090] ;
etc.
```

From this we see that this call of `append/3` defines a relation between its arguments, and we see the following pattern:

`L` always consists of:

- `H` as the first element
- followed by all elements in `T`
- followed by a suffix.

This is not suprising, since that's exactly what `append([H|Ts], _, Ls)` means: `[H|Ts]` followed by *any list at all* constitutes the list `Ls`.

In your concrete use case, it is obvious that `L` is meant to be **instantiated**, and so the suffix cannot be arbitrarily long.

For example:

```
?- append([H|T], _, [a,b,c]).
H = a,
T = [] ;
H = a,
T = [b] ;
H = a,
T = [b, c] ;
false.
```

And so we see the meaning of the whole clause (I have renamed the variables so that lists are denoted by the suffix **s** in variable names):

```
powerset(Ls, [H|Ts]):-
    append([H|Ts], _, Ls).
```

**If** `Ls` is a list that contains as its first element `H`, followed by elements `Ts`, followed by *anything at all*, **then** the list `[H|Ts]` is a member of the powerset of `L`.

Informally:

> Every nonempty prefix of the list is a member of the powerset.

And from this we also see a glaring omission of `powerset/2` as it appears in this thread: None of the clauses yields the **empty set** as a member of the powerset, and even more disturbingly, none of them *accepts* the empty set as a valid set, so the following incorrectly **fails**:

```
?- powerset([], _).
false. % empty set is not a set?
```

**Exercise**: Correct `powerset/2` so that it actually succeeds for all elements of the powerset.